Unable to access Data Access objects in Rooms database object
I am using  the Rooms database library version 2.6.1 to  integrate database functionality in my test android application. The application compiles successfully but the problem I am facing is that I am unable to access the 'Data Access Object' from the Room datbase reference object
Database configuration
    package com.example.expensesrecorder.database
    
    import androidx.room.Database
    import androidx.room.RoomDatabase
    import androidx.room.TypeConverters
    import com.example.expensesrecorder.database.databaseaccessobjects.CategoryDao
    import com.example.expensesrecorder.database.databaseaccessobjects.ExpenseDao
    import com.example.expensesrecorder.database.entities.Category
    import com.example.expensesrecorder.database.entities.Expense
    import com.example.expensesrecorder.database.typeconvertors.ZonedDateTimeConverter
    
    @Database(entities = [Expense::class, Category::class], version = 1)
    @TypeConverters(
        value = [ZonedDateTimeConverter::class]
    )
     abstract class ExpenseDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
        abstract fun expenseDao(): ExpenseDao
        abstract fun categoryDao(): CategoryDao
    }


Android application class
import android.app.Application
import androidx.room.Room
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase
import com.example.expensesrecorder.database.ExpenseDatabase

class AndroidApp : Application() {

    lateinit var myRoomDatabase: RoomDatabase

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        myRoomDatabase = Room
            .databaseBuilder(applicationContext, ExpenseDatabase::class.java, "expense_database")
            .build()
    }
}

Category Data Access object
package com.example.expensesrecorder.database.databaseaccessobjects

import androidx.room.Dao
import androidx.room.Delete
import androidx.room.Insert
import androidx.room.Query
import com.example.expensesrecorder.database.entities.Category
import com.example.expensesrecorder.database.entities.Expense

@Dao
 interface CategoryDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM Category")
     fun getAll(): List<Category>



    @Insert
    fun insertAll(vararg users: Category)

    @Delete
    fun delete(user: Category)
}

Expense Data Access object
import androidx.room.Dao
import androidx.room.Delete
import androidx.room.Insert
import androidx.room.Query
import com.example.expensesrecorder.database.entities.Expense

@Dao
 interface ExpenseDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM expense")
    fun getAll(): List<Expense>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM expense WHERE uid IN (:userIds)")
    fun loadAllByIds(userIds: IntArray): List<Expense>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM expense WHERE expense_title LIKE :first AND " +
            "expense_title LIKE :last LIMIT 1")
    fun findByName(first: String, last: String): Expense

    @Insert
    fun insertAll(vararg users: Expense)

    @Delete
    fun delete(user: Expense)
}


Category Entity
package com.example.expensesrecorder.database.entities

import androidx.room.ColumnInfo
import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey
import java.time.ZonedDateTime

@Entity(tableName="category")
data class Category(
    @PrimaryKey val uid: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "category_title") val categoryTitle: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "category_description") val categoryDescription: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "category_status") val categoryStatus: Boolean?

)

Expense Entity
package com.example.expensesrecorder.database.entities

import androidx.room.ColumnInfo
import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey
import java.text.DecimalFormat
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import java.time.ZonedDateTime
import java.util.Date

@Entity(tableName="expense")
data class Expense(
    @PrimaryKey val uid: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "expense_title") val expenseTitle: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "expense_description") val expenseDescription: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "expense_category_id") val expenseCategoryId: String?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "expense_amount") val expenseAmount: Double,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "expense_date") val expenseDate: ZonedDateTime
)


Finally when I try the code below in my activity (oncreate event). I am unable to access the 'catgoryDao' or 'expenseDao' methods eventhough they appear in the implementation that appears in the build folder
val mApplication: AndroidApp = applicationContext as AndroidApp
            val expenseDao= mApplication.myRoomDatabase.expenseDao() 

I get a 'unresolved reference' error
I have been googling for a solution for the last couple of days
Thanks in advance for any tips
regards
Mathew

Have you tried invalidate cache and restart

Thanks for responding
Unfortunately running the 'invalidate cache and restart' option didnt help

Finally after lots of debugging I understood that when a variable (used to store a reference to a Room database) that has been defined in a class that extends 'Application' it needs to be cast to the database configuration class (in my case the class is named 'ExpenseDatabase) in order to access the Dao methods.
So I added the statement below in the 'oncreate' event of my activity to get access to 'DAO' methods
val expenseDao= (mApplication.myRoomDatabase as ExpenseDatabase).expenseDao()

Earlier I was trying
val expenseDao= mApplication.myRoomDatabase.expenseDao() 

I am not sure about why the cast needs to be made
Hope it helps someone
Thanks and regards
Mathew

Instead of this lateinit var myRoomDatabase: RoomDatabase lateinit var myRoomDatabase: ExpenseDatabase

thanks for your response
Yes, that change can avoid casting to an object of type while trying to access the DAo class
but in  all the examples on the internet nowhere is such a cast to the class used for database configuration (in my case ExpenseDatabase) made. Thats whats getting me confused
